# Find whether current date is same as previous date

Tags: r, date

I have these date times:

```
library(lubridate)
my_date_times <- dmy_hm(c("17/05/16 23:49", "17/05/16 09:39", "08/08/16 23:21", "08/12/16 09:23", "26/02/17 08:03", "12/10/17 12:04", "12/10/17 10:03"))
```

I want to calculate whether a date is the same as the date in the previous row. If the current date is the same as the previous, then I would to add TRUE to both rows in the `same_date` variable. I'm not concerned if the two times do not match. Hopefully this code explains what I'm after.

```
same_date <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
library(tibble)
df <- data_frame(my_date_times, same_date)
df 

# A tibble: 7 x 2
        my_date_times same_date
               <dttm>     <lgl>
1 2016-05-17 23:49:00      TRUE
2 2016-05-17 09:39:00      TRUE
3 2016-08-08 23:21:00     FALSE
4 2016-12-08 09:23:00     FALSE
5 2017-02-26 08:03:00     FALSE
6 2017-10-12 12:04:00      TRUE
7 2017-10-12 10:03:00      TRUE
```

Comment: `df$same_date <- c(T, diff(as.Date(df$my_date_times))==0)`?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The OP has requested to add `TRUE` to *both rows* if the current date is the same as the previous. This is why the `diff()` approach won't work here.

Instead, we can group by date and check whether the group consists only of one row or multiple rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, same_date  := .N > 1, by = as.Date(my_date_times)][]
```

> ```
>          my_date_times same_date
> 1: 2016-05-17 23:49:00      TRUE
> 2: 2016-05-17 09:39:00      TRUE
> 3: 2016-08-08 23:21:00     FALSE
> 4: 2016-12-08 09:23:00     FALSE
> 5: 2017-02-26 08:03:00     FALSE
> 6: 2017-10-12 12:04:00      TRUE
> 7: 2017-10-12 10:03:00      TRUE
> ```